# Allow vhost and standard localhost

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost

Hello guys am not realy good with apache and i have litle problem when i need to create virtual host for one project.Until now, I have accessed all projects via a browser in the following way:
`http://localhost/`

Now we need to create a new project that requires the virtual host that we successfully created.

The problem is that now when we visit `http://localhost/`, the other files that were displayed are not displayed, but only the virtual host is displayed.

How is it possible to show `http://localhost/` as it was before and the virtual host shows only the directory for which it is configured?

**This is how we created vhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName opencart.local
    DocumentRoot "D:\xamp-php-8.1\htdocs\opencart-4.0.2.1\upload
    <Directory "D:\xamp-php-8.1\htdocs\opencart-4.0.2.1\upload">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And we change `hosts` file adding this line

`127.0.0.1 opencart.local`

So we want when we visit localhost to show all files from `D:\xamp-php-8.1\htdocs\`
When we visit `opencart.local` to show only that document root

With this we get
**Internal Server Error**

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: You can have MANY Virtual Hosts. Reapply the one you had for localhost as well as the new one